# Value not passing between viewControllers

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller

Struggling to get my viewControllers to send value from the main viewController to a second. I want it to happen on a button click, I'm going to get the value from the button and pass it to the new form. But it just isn't working.

Code for main ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func butClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
    NSLog("Button Pressed : %@",[sender .currentTitle])
    //var tt = [sender .currentTitle]
    // Create the view controller
    let vc = TimesTablesViewController(nibName: "TimesTablesViewController", bundle: nil)
    vc.passedValue = "xx"
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "pushSegue", sender: nil)

}
}
```

Code for second viewController called TimesTablesViewController:

```
class TimesTablesViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

var passedValue:String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    titleLabel?.text = "\(passedValue) Times Table"
}

}
```

I've followed tutorials but can't seem to solve the problem! Thanks for any help!

Comment: Delete `let vc = TimesTablesViewController(nibName: "TimesTablesViewController", bundle: nil); vc.passedValue = "xx"` and implement `prepareForSegue` to pass the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "pushSegue", sender: nil)
```

with

```
self.present(vc,animated:true,completion:nil)
```

or ( if the current vc is inside a naigation )

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc,animated:true)
```

Using

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "pushSegue", sender: nil)
```

is fit with storyboards not xibs and if this your case then you need to  use the above line only inside the button action with implementing this method inside the source vc

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "pushSegue"  {
        if let nextViewController = segue.destination as? TimesTablesViewController{
                nextViewController.passedValue = "xx"  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not completely correct. He didn't instantiate the view controller correctly, so he can't push or present it.

Comment: from what info in post you thought it's storyboard ? and if so this is already answered

Comment: My bad. It is a bit late now, and my brain might be too tired. Sorry

Comment: The method below solved my issue. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I’m assuming that the new view controller is appearing, but you’re simply not seeing the data. If so, you’re evidently using storyboards. The `TimesTablesViewController(nibName:bundle:)` only works if you’re using XIB/NIBs and manually presenting new view controller.

If you’re really using storyboards, simplify your `butClick` method:

```
@IBAction func butClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
    NSLog("Button Pressed")
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "pushSegue", sender: self)
}
```

But implement `prepare(for:sender:)`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? TimesTablesViewController {
        destination.passedValue = "xx"
    }
}
```

---

Assuming the above fixes your problem, I might suggest a further simplification. Notably, if your `butClick(_:)` method is really only calling `performSegue`, you can segue to this next scene without any `@IBAction` method at all:

- remove `butClick(_:)` entirely;
- remove the connection between the button and the `butClick` method in IB, on the “Connections Inspector” tab in the right panel; and
- <kbd>control</kbd>-drag from the button previously hooked up to `butClick(_:)` to the scene for `TimesTablesViewController`.

That will simplify your code further.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I still think I need the button event as I take the text from the button.